# How to drop a table referincing a very trafficated table easily?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, locking, drop-table

Let's say I have this two tables

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    id_user serial primary key,
    name text NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE useless_table (
    id serial primary key,
    id_user int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT useless_table_id_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_user) REFERENCES users(id_user)
);
```

`users` is the most congested table in all the database, with queries going non-stop, even long and important ones, so I just cannot kill all of them.
I want to drop `useless_table` that, as you can see, has a foreign key referencing `users`, and every time I launch the `DROP` command it gets a lock with even the simplest `SELECT` on `users` (there aren't any query going on `useless_table`). I even tried to drop the foreign key on `useless_table` but it gets the same locks as the drop of the table.

Maybe I'm dreamer, but is there a way to don't make it lock with everything and just drop `useless_table`?

I'm thinking about `NOT VALID` foreign keys, disabling triggers, deferrable constraints or things of this type, but I'm not very savvy about them and don't want to make a mess using them.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I’d try dropping the constraint and then drop the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The users of "users" have to somehow know that they are no longer required to ensure the referential integrity to "useless_table", and the only safe way for them to know that is by changing the metadata of "users", which requires a lock.

You will either need to declare a maintenance window, or just get lucky enough to catch "users" in a state where it is unlocked.  You could run the below in a loop until on some fortunate attempt it succeeds (The nowait will throw an error immediately if the lock is not available).  You would probably want to throttle it to not loop as fast possible, as otherwise it will put a lot of contention on some LWLocks/spinlocks, which you probably don't want.

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE "users" nowait;
DROP TABLE "useless_table";
COMMIT;
```

Comment: What about dropping the FK constraint, and then dropping the table?

Comment: @RonJohn Dropping the constraint still needs the lock on the other table, so I don't see the point in doing it separately.